# Example(s) of reduced rate of mitotic progression?

Tags: cell-biology, chromosome, mitosis

Most species complete mitosis, and in particular the process of chromosome condensation, rather quickly, in a matter of minutes. Are there any known species that undergo mitoses with substantially reduced kinetics (on the time scale of hours), particularly with respect to the processes of chromosome condensation (prophase through metaphase) or decondensation (anaphase through telophase)?

Comment: don't know about mitosis but oocytes are locked in metphase for several years.. the second round of meiosis (gametogenesis) begins only at puberty.